# Apex Action in Flow is not executing when it's being called under guest user context

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, force.com-sites, invocable-method, guest-user

I have a managed package in my Salesforce instance, and I'm trying to implement a flow that is a record trigger flow on Event__c (custom object).

I'm creating the Event__c record by exposing a URL through a public site and making the events through it.

When the events are created in Salesforce, the flow starts to execute and finishes the execution. Still, the apex action (a part of the managed package) is not executed.

Also, I tested all the permission of the object being used in the managed package, and they are returning the details using the site user.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the Apex Class to the Guest User Profile as well?

Comment: @SarojBera yes, I already did that.